# Can UITableViewController toolbar buttons be changed when in Edit mode?

Tags: swift, uitableview, toolbar, uibarbuttonitem

I've created a Storyboard project with a simple TableViewController embedded in a NavigationController with a simple toolbar at the bottom of the TableView. All done through the storyboard using the NavigationController ShowsToolbar=Y method described in other posts.

Is it possible to change the bottom toolbar buttons when the TableView goes into Edit mode? For example the Apple Mail app toolbar buttons change when you click on Edit.

From what I understand my options are to programmatically add remove bar button items when the TableView goes into edit more or to change the Edit button to segue to another TableView set in Edit mode with its own navigation controller and toolbar.

I thought it would be a more commonly done thing and therefore more obvious how to do it but haven't found anything so far.

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: It would be best if you learn formally rather than exploring by trial and error as you might find it frustrating / not learn the proper way to do things. Stanford iOS videos are a good way to start https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-10-apps-with-swift/id1198467120

Comment: Swift - https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-3-1/id881256329?mt=11

Comment: Thanks for the Stanford recommendation. Excellent set of lectures.